# Sound jumping between speakers and headphones when volume is high

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones, speakers

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, but had this problem on previous versions of Ubuntu.

When the volume is higher than 45% and I am playing music the sound switches between head phones and speakers, but there is no headphones plugged in.

It does not matter which program is used to play music with.

Answer (score 0):

Try plugging in headphones and turning the volume down, then unplug them and re test. I had a similar problem and that did it for me.